# Why does this following program print "Yes" instead of "No"?

Tags: c, boolean

Why does this following program print "Yes" instead of "No"?

None of the variables is initialized to 2.

```
    bool hello = 0;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 3;
    int c = 4;
    int d = 5;

    if (a || b || c || d == 2) {
        hello = 1;
    }

    if (hello == 1) {
        printf("Yes");
    }

    if (hello == 0) {
        printf("No");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because `hello == 1` is true. So, what *makes* `hello` be 1? Work backwards. You may want to review the `||` operator; and note the first expression is the same as `a || b || c || (d == 2)`.

Comment: You probably want `if (a == 2 || b == 2 || c ==2 || d == 2)` imstead of `if (a || b || c || d == 2)`. `if (a || b || c || d == 2)` is the same as `if (a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0 || d == 2)`

Comment: there are a lot of duplicates but it's hard to find right now

Answer (score 7):

The statement

```
if (a || b || c || d == 2)
```

is equivalent to:

```
if (a != 0 || b != 0 || c != 0 || d == 2)
```

The equality comparison does not automatically distribute across all the variables. If you want to do that, you need to perform all the comparisons explicitly:

```
if (a == 2 || b == 2 || c ==2 || d == 2)
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `(a || b || c || d == 2)` evalutates to `true` because it treats a, b, c as booleans, and any non-zero integer is true.

Answer (score 3):

You have given logical operator in the expression It means that if non zero value came then the  expression is true. Then hello=1 is set and in next f statement it prints YES

Answer (score 1):

You just meet the *short circuit* behavior of logical expressions [OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f355wky8.aspx).

The [order of evaluation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) of logical *OR* `||` is left to right.

So in the following expression:

```
left || right
```

if `left = true` then `right` will never going to be executed (short circuit). In your code exactly same happened.

As you know, any *non zero* value treated as `true` in C, hence, `a` which is `1` is `true`. So, take a look:

```
if (a || b || c || d == 2)
if (true || bla bla bla) //rights are not even checked!
if (true) 
hello = 1;
```

Tada! So the program print "Yes"!

> None of the variables is initialized to 2.

Yes of course! But your `if` condition is not going to check that. To do so, try this:

```
if (a == 2 || b == 2 || c ==2 || d == 2) {
    //...
```

Comment: It would give the same result if the order were right to left and there were no short-circuiting, since none of the expressions have side effects or order dependencies.

Comment: His problem is that he translated the English "either a or b or c or d is equal to 2" into "a | b | c | d == 2", but the rules are different in English and programming.

Answer (score 0):

because  if judge num is not zero , if think this is true. so your code

```
 if (a || b || c || d == 2)
 like 
 if ( true || true || true || false)
```

the result is true, programe print "YES"